# super minimalist plugin for MS Project: where to get started?

Tags: c#, .net, c++, vb.net, ms-project

I was wondering if you could point me in the right direction as far as developing a super simple plugin for MS Project (both 2007, which uses the old style ribbon, and 2010 which uses the new ribbon). 
What I need to implement:

- create an executable that installs a new button, with a specific icon, in some per-determined section of the ribbon
- when the user presses the button MS project needs to save a file in a specific format and location and then call a batch file.

that's it - pretty basic, right? Turns out, I know nothing about this space - so apologies in advance for how trivial this may be. Note: I'm not tied to a specific language - whatever is simpler / faster will do.

BTW, does anyone sell components like this one? I don't necessarily need to code this if there's decent stuff out there for sale.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try here: http://www.add-in-express.com/support/addin-c-sharp.php#project

This was also answered here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/280e11ec-9bbc-4d13-bda1-3e053c8d55c7